# Are Barbarians ever able to dual-wield 2-handed weapons?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-barbarian

I know they can dual wield single handed weapons, are they ever able to dual wield the two handed weapons, as in some other games?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been possible using a glitch before, but it's now patched.
So dual wield 2-handed weapons is not possible anymore.